# how to get values from 2 edit text and sum it and show it into third edit text without any button

Tags: android

How can I get the values from two `EditText`, sum it, and show it into a third `EditText` without clicking a button?

Here is my code so far

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int a,b,c;
    EditText fst= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fstdgt);
    EditText scnd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.scnddgt);
    EditText thrd= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.thrddgt);
    View v;

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        a=Integer.parseInt(fst.getText().toString());
        b=Integer.parseInt(scnd.getText().toString());
        c=a+b;
        thrd.setText("" + c);
    }
}
```

This is not working. The app crashes every time it starts. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: because you are not assigning any value to a,b and to get text without clicking use text change listener

Comment: Mk. You're going to have to add some more details. What does Logcat say when the app crashes? Do your textboxes initially contain any text? What exactly do you want the behavior to be? Should the third textbox update only when the app starts? Or should it change whenever the other two textboxes are updated?

Comment: in logcat it says null pointer exception

Comment: mohit can u plz code for just two lines to give me a hint

Comment: Andrew it should change whenever i change values in the fst and second edit text

Answer (score 1):

Adding a textchange listener to both of your input editboxes will solve your problem. This is how I think it should be done to solve your problem:

> ```
> int a, b,c;
> String input_a = fst.getText().toString();
> String input_b = scnd.getText().toString();
>
> fst.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>             @Override
>             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
>                 if (!input_a.isEmpty() && !intput_b.isEmpty()){
>                     a = Integer.parseInt(input_a);
>                     b= Integer.parseInt(input_b);
>                     c = a+b;
>                     String answer_value= "" + c;
>                     thrd.setText(answer_value);
>                 } else thrd.setText("");
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
>
>             }
>         });
> //and you need to add TextChangeListener for your "scnd" editText as well.
> scnd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
>             @Override
>             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
>                 if (!input_a.isEmpty() && !input_b.isEmpty()){
>                     a = Integer.parseInt(input_a);
>                     b= Integer.parseInt(input_b);
>                     c = a+b;
>                     String answer_value= "" + c;
>                     thrd.setText(answer_value);
>                 } else thrd.setText("");
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
>
>             }
>         });
> ```